¿Se puede crear una tabla filtrada a partir de otra en DAX?
espero alguien me pueda ayudar aunque no estoy seguro si es posible hacerse con DAX.
Estoy trabajando con una tabla que tiene la siguiente estructura:



ID
FECHA
Cantidad




1
01/07/2024
1,000


1
08/07/2024
3,000


2
12/07/2024
500


3
15/07/2024
1,500


3
22/07/2024
1,000


3
29/07/2024
500


4
12/07/2024
2,500


4
15/07/2024
2,500


5
01/07/2024
500


5
08/07/2024
750


5
29/07/2024
250


5
12/07/2024
500



Lo que intento hacer es crear una nueva tabla a partir de esta, pero con la diferencia de que la nueva tabla me traiga solo las filas en que la suma de la columna cantidad me de igual o mayor a 2500, esto por ID y tomando en cuenta el orden de la columna fecha.
O en otras palabras más sencillas, tener una tabla donde me muestre por ID en cuantas "compras" igualo o supero la cantidad de 2500, respetando el orden de las fechas.
Por ejemplo el resultado sería este:



ID
FECHA
Cantidad




1
01/07/2024
1,000


1
08/07/2024
3,000


2
12/07/2024
500


3
15/07/2024
1,500


3
22/07/2024
1,000


4
12/07/2024
2,500


5
01/07/2024
500


5
08/07/2024
750


5
29/07/2024
250


5
12/07/2024
500



Intente crear una tabla filtrada pero no logro como indicarle a la formula hasta que punto me filtre las filas por ID para que solo me muestre las que en suma me de igual o mayor a 2500.
Si alguien ha echo algo parecido me seria de gran ayuda su respuesta, Muchas gracias.
